# APNS Connection Issue

Tags: apple-push-notifications, apns-php

OK, I know there has been a lot of discussion regarding APNS connection failures.  Most of the discussion recommends checking the outgoing server port 2195 to be sure it will allow the connection.  This is not my problem, although I am experiencing the 'connection refused' error (111).

I have validated communication between my server and the sandbox server be receiving a 200 response from the Apple Gateway.  I know my certificates are good because I have tested the connection using openssl from a Mac.  I have also been able to connect with the gateway ***once*** from my server but cannot get a consistent connection.

The test code I am using is as follows:

```
$ctx = stream_context_create();

stream_context_set_option($ctx,'ssl', 'local_cert', $pem);
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $key);
$gateway = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
$port = '2195';

$remote_socket = 'ssl://'.$gateway.':'.$port;
$fp = stream_socket_client($remote_socket, $err, $errstr, 60,STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);

if (!$fp){
    echo $err.'<br>';
    echo $errstr.'</br>';
    echo 'error=apple failed to connect';
} else {
    fclose($fp);
    echo 'success';
}
```

I have placed the .pem file in the same directory as the script file, removed the use of the passphrase, specified verify_peer, used the STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT and the STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT flags without success.

Is this an issue with something that I am doing, an issue with the apns sandbox server or is this what I should expect from the apns?  Any insights or help you can provide is greatly appreciated -- my hair is getting pretty thin!

Regards.

PS -- If I remove the passphrase I get a 115 error saying the key cannot be accessed.

Answer (score 2):

Despite being able to connect at least once, it turns out that you cannot get access to the APNS gateway without, at least, a virtual dedicated server on GoDaddy.  At a minimum of $80 per month, paid upfront, that is too expensive.  On to other means.

Answer (score 1):

Some other things to try :

1. Use **STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT** in the stream_socket_client call
2. Don't use verify_peer
3. Check that the owner of the PHP script has enough rights to read the pem file and connect to a port located elsewhere (ie/ not just localhost)

Comment: Thanks Nick.  

I have  already tried the STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT flags and eliminated the verify_peer option without success.  I have the test script on an active web connected development site and the pem file is readable.  While I have been able to connect once, I am beginning to think it is a port 2195 restriction issue.   I have to do some more research on this.  I'll post a response as soon as I know.